# Unable to set back button title ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am new to iOS,

I want to set empty text to all back button on UINavigationBar globally because i have multiple UINavigationBar so thought to try using category.

Here is my code:

**UINavigationItem+BackButton.h**

```
@interface UINavigationItem (BackButton)
- (void)removeBackText;
@end
```

**UINavigationItem+BackButton.m**

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (BackButton)
- (void)removeBackText
{
    self.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bc" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];    
}
@end
```

In one of my ViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationItem removeBackText];

}
```

I have tried this but its not working.
Can any help help where i am doing mistake?

***Thank you in advance***

Comment: Try `self.navigationItem` instead of `self.navigationController.navigationItem`

Comment: tried but same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in your `removeBackText` method

```
- (void)removeBackText
{
    self.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];    
}
```

Here `initWithTitle:@""` not `initWithTitle:@"Bc"`

And also you need to change your `viewWillAppear` method to add back barButton on navigation bar like below.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton;
```

Comment: what is `myBackButton`?

Comment: @KrunalJitendraLathiyaTechno it's object of barButton item